# How to extract a text in a file python

Tags: python

How to extract a text in a file with python.
- A text begin with chaine.

My code is

```
fichier= open("Service.txt", "r")
for ligne in fichier:
  if ligne==chaine:
  #What do I do ? 
fichier.close()
```

Comment: use `if ligne.startswith("chaine")` then do whatever you like with ligne.

Comment: You want to extract all text starting from line that starts from chaine?

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stack Overflow :) It will be easier for you to get help in the long run if you make the effort to program in English. You don't need a big vocabulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood question correctly:

**test.txt**

```
fsdfj ljkjl
sdfsdf ljkkk
some ldfff
fffl lll
ppppp
```

**script:**

```
chaine = 'some'

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
    i = text.find(chaine)
    print(text[i:])
```

**output:**

```
some ldfff
fffl lll
ppppp
```

Comment: Thank you all. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `in` operator with string.

Like

```
>>> a = "cheine is good"
>>> "cheine" in a
True
```

So your code must be like.

```
fichier= open("Service.txt", "r")
for ligne in fichier:
  if chaine in ligne:
  #What do I do ? 
fichier.close()
```

If you have to check start only in line, then you can check `ligne.startswith`.

Comment: Thank you all. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("Service.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
chaines = [line for line in lines if line.startswith("chaine")]
for chaine in chaines:
    print("Some chaine, whatever that is", chaine)
```

This uses a list comprehension, the `if` part will filter out any line that doesn't start with `"chaine"`.

The `with` block is a context manager, it makes sure to close the file when the block ends, even if there is an exception.

Comment: Thank you all. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
>>> with open('Service.txt', 'r') as f:
...     val = f.read()
>>> if "cheine" in val:
... # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("Service.txt", "r") as fichier:
    for ligne in fichier.readlines():
      if 'Call' in ligne:
      #What do I do
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

This is a file (Service.txt) while, I use to recover a text with it.

A text is only:

```
     Supplementary service  =  Call forwarding unconditional


                            =  Call waiting


                            =  Calling line identification presentation
```

[Service.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vURNk.png)

Thank you.

Comment: A text is not fixed.